# Add row to Form Layout

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

code:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QMainWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle("First GUI")
    form_widget = QWidget()
    form_widget.layout = QFormLayout()
    form_widget.layout.addRow(QLabel("city 1"), QLabel("delhi"))
    form_widget.layout.addRow(QLabel("city 2"), QLabel("chennai"))
    main.setCentralWidget(form_widget)

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Above code opened an empty window with "First GUI" as title.

But rows were not added to that window. *Why ? How to correct this ?*

Comment: May be you need to set size to your layout?

Comment: Style nitpick: `addRow` doesn't need the explicit instantiation of `QLabel` for the first argument. You can invoke it simply as `form_widget.layout.addRow("city 1", QLabel("delhi"))`.

Comment: @folibis The whole point of layouts is that you don't need to explicitly deal with their sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`setLayout()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setLayout) to assign the layout to the widget.

```
form_widget = QWidget()
layout = QFormLayout()
layout.addRow(QLabel("city 1"), QLabel("delhi"))
layout.addRow(QLabel("city 2"), QLabel("chennai"))
form_widget.setLayout(layout)
```

Comment: Alternatively, pass the `form_widget` as argument to `QFormLayout`. It saves one line of code - the `setLayout` call is not needed anymore.